# How to disable the bounce effect of Scroll Viewer in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, scroll, viewer

i wanna disable the bounce effect of Scroll Viewer,how can i do that?

Comment: What "bounce effect" are you referring to?

Comment: If you mean the effect that you get when scrolling to the bottom of the list, please don't. You're not a designer, don't break platform uniformity.

Comment: i just made a table with 3 scroll viewers,i want to avoid the situation that the content is separate away from its header,so i have to  disable the effect optionally,either the horizontal or the vertical one,depending on the scroll direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the ScrollViewer uses a [ScrollContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollcontentpresenter.aspx), and this one doesn't show any type of properties to change the bounce behavior nor it has a Template property that we could edit to change the control behavior...

Comment: None that I'm aware of... I think this is a system/framework behavior and it cannot be changed! All I can think of is you making your own scrollviewercontrol, but I guess that will be a lot of work to achieve...

Comment: yep.if i could,i would but i have no idea on how to make a scroll viewer myself.do you have any resources that i can refer to please?

Comment: Best I can think of is to direct you to the [WrapPanel source code](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/76139#1510352)... all it misses is the scrolling behavior! :)