# How to turn off windows 8 phone vertical Bouncing Effect

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8

Can anyone please tell me how to turn off the windows 8 phone Bouncing Effect? When I display Page, the page is not fixed. I can drag it top and bottom and shows white space.Can anyone please tell me how to fix the Page without moving?

I am sure there will be some property to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a programming question or are you looking for support of your device? Stackoverflow is geared towards answering specific programming questions so if that's what you're asking it would help if you posted a minimal test case you're dealing with, what you expect to happen and what's actually happening.

Comment: This is just the way the browser works on WP8. It's unrelated to programming and you can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question to yours but regarding Windows Phone 7.

[How to disable the bounce effect of Scroll Viewer in wp7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663020/how-to-disable-the-bounce-effect-of-scroll-viewer-in-wp7)

I did additional research and it still looks like there is no way of doing this unless you want to override the ScrollCotentPresenter class which could be quite some work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollcontentpresenter(v=vs.95).aspx

All the properties of ScrollCotentPresenter class are shown there and none of them seem to allow modification of the bounce feature.